# 4x4 Grid in python?

Tags: python, grid

I have been making a game in which a 3x3 grid and a 4x4 grid need to be displayed.
This is the code I used for the 3x3 grid, which worked:

```
try:
    with open('Words.txt', "r") as f:#opens the text file
        words = f.read().split()
        random.shuffle(words)#shuffles the words in the grid
        replacement = words[0]
        removed = words[1]
        words.remove(replacement)

grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
for x,y,z in grid:
    print(x,y,z)#displays grid
```

However, I am not sure how to do this for a 4x4 grid. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This might sound totally crazy. Have you tried replacing all instances of "3" with "4" in your source code?

Comment: @HearthStrike If you've tried to solve your problem and got an error, please edit your question to include your attempted solution, and the error that resulted. That way, people can help you track down the problem.

Comment: Try a few things. For instance - print out `grid` just after you define it (e.g. `print(grid)`.  Put 300 words in `Words.txt` and see what your existing code does.  It might be quite revealing.

Comment: Thanks ill give that a go and let you kniw

Answer (score 0):

I think in your file: len(words)%4 != 0

try this:

```
import random

with open('Words.txt', "r") as f:#opens the text file
    words = f.read().split()
    random.shuffle(words)#shuffles the words in the grid
    replacement = words[0]
    removed = words[1]
    words.remove(replacement)

grid = [words[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(words), 4)]
r = len(words)%4

if r==0:
    for x,y,z,k in grid:
        print(x,y,z,k) #displays grid
else:
    grid = grid[: -1]
    for x,y,z,k in grid:
        print(x,y,z,k) #displays grid
```

Comment: Hmm, whilst I can see the intent here - aren't you assuming here that `Words.txt` contains either exactly `16` or exactly `17`, `18` or `19` words. Otherwise the grid can't be guaranteed to be 4 x 4

Comment: It does to your output - if it's 22, you'll get a 4 x 5 grid, if it's 1922, you'll get a 4 x 480 grid - i.e. it will only output 4 x 4 in the specific conditions I mention...

Comment: you're right. The file has to have 16-19 words in it.